# How to speed up data loading into recyclerview?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-recyclerview

I'm in a dire situation of finding a solution for speeding up loading data into the `RecyclerView`. Data load from the server database and populate the row. Each row has a few `EditTexts` where user enters some values. Within the `OnBindViewHolder`, each value entered by the user is captured using a text watcher, and then totals are calculated and displayed real-time in the footer of the parent view.(outside the `RecyclerView`) Also, inside the `OnBindViewHolder`, a method is called to update a `table` in the DB, with the values just entered and captured.

So, basically, when each row gets bound, both the DB and the UI get updated. When the data load is huge, loading of the `recyclerView` is really slow. What I have tried are moving the DB update to a separate thread, using `async task` to update the DB. But nothing worked. What should I do here?

Adapter's OnBindViewHolder code is displayed below.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position, List<Object> payload) {
        //onBindViewHolder(holder,position);

        holder.ref = position;
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

        onBind = true;

        // data passed from getAllData method aka all from TempInvoice
        SalesInvoiceModel siModel = salesInvoice.get(position);

        holder.code.setText(siModel.getCode());
        holder.product.setText(siModel.getProduct());
        holder.batchNum.setText(siModel.getBatchNumber());
        try {
            Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(siModel.getExpiryDate());
            holder.expiry.setText(date.toString());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            holder.expiry.setText("Error");
        }
        holder.expiry.setText(siModel.getExpiryDate());

        if (siModel.getDiscountRate() > 0) {
            holder.unitprice.setText(siModel.getRetailPrice() + "");
        } else {
            holder.unitprice.setText(siModel.getUnitPrice() + "");
        }

        holder.stock.setText(siModel.getStock() + "");
        holder.lineval.setText(siModel.getLineValue() + "");

        if (payload == null || payload.size() == 0) {
            holder.shelf.setText(siModel.getShelf() + "");
            holder.request.setText(siModel.getRequest() + "");
            holder.order.setText(siModel.getOrder() + "");
            holder.free.setText(siModel.getFree() + "");
            holder.discount.setText(siModel.getDiscountRate() + "");
        } else {

            for (Object editText : payload) {
                //String val = (String)payload.get(0);
                String val = (String) editText;
                switch (val) {
                    case SHELF:

                        if (lostFocus) {
                            holder.shelf.setText(salesInvoice.get(position).getShelf() + "");
                        }
                        break;
                    case REQUEST:

                        if (lostFocus) {
                            holder.request.setText(salesInvoice.get(position).getRequest() + "");
                        }
                        break;
                    case ORDER:
                        if (lostFocus) {
                            holder.order.setText(salesInvoice.get(position).getOrder() + "");
                        }
                        break;
                    case FREE:
                        if (lostFocus) {
                            holder.free.setText(salesInvoice.get(position).getFree() + "");
                        }
                        break;
                    case DISCOUNT:
                        if (lostFocus) {
                            holder.discount.setText(salesInvoice.get(position).getDiscountRate() + "");
                        }
                        break;

                    case LINEVAL:
                        holder.lineval.setText(salesInvoice.get(position).getLineValue() + "");
                        break;
                    default:
                        onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
                        break;
                }
            }

        }

        //ADD TEXT WATCHERS


        holder.shelf.setOnFocusChangeListener(new FocusChangeListener());
        holder.shelf.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(String s) {

                int pos = holder.ref;
                if (!onBind) {
                    if (!s.equals("")) {
                        notifyItemChanged(pos, SHELF);
                        Log.d(TAG, "inside text change typed shelf_" + s);
                        salesInvoice.get(pos).setShelf(Integer.parseInt(s + ""));


                    } else {
                        salesInvoice.get(pos).setShelf(0);
                    }
                    lastUpdatedRow = pos;
                }
            }
        });

        holder.request.setOnFocusChangeListener(new FocusChangeListener());
        holder.request.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(String s) {
                boolean valHasChanged = false;
                boolean freeHasChanged = false;
                int pos = holder.ref;
                if (!onBind) {

                    if (!(s.equals(""))) {

                        int val = Integer.parseInt((s));
                        int stock = salesInvoice.get(pos).getStock();
                        // if stock does not have the particular product
                        if (val > stock) {
                            val = stock;
                            valHasChanged = true;
                        }
                        salesInvoice.get(pos).setRequest(val);
                        if (!refresh) salesInvoice.get(pos).setOrder(val);

                        if (salesInvoice.get(pos).getFree() + salesInvoice.get(pos).getOrder() > salesInvoice.get(pos).getStock()) {
                            salesInvoice.get(pos).setFree(0);
                            freeHasChanged = true;

                        }

                    } else {
                        salesInvoice.get(pos).setRequest(0);
                    }

                    notifyItemChanged(pos, ORDER);

                    if (valHasChanged) {
                        notifyItemChanged(pos, REQUEST);
                    }
                    if (freeHasChanged) {
                        notifyItemChanged(pos, FREE);
                    }

                    lastUpdatedRow = pos;
                }

            }
        });

        holder.order.setOnFocusChangeListener(new FocusChangeListener());
        holder.order.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(String s) {
                boolean valHasChanged = false;
                boolean freeHasChanged = false;
                int pos = holder.ref;


                if (!onBind) {
                    if (!(s.equals(""))) {

                        int val = Integer.parseInt(s);
                        int stock = salesInvoice.get(pos).getStock();

                        if (val > stock) {
                            val = stock;
                            valHasChanged = true;

                        }
                        salesInvoice.get(pos).setOrder(val);//make sure we set returnQty before
                        //checking the total of returnQty and free against stock

                        if (salesInvoice.get(pos).getOrder() + salesInvoice.get(pos).getFree() > salesInvoice.get(pos).getStock()) {
                            salesInvoice.get(pos).setFree(0);
                            freeHasChanged = true;
                        }



                    } else {
                        salesInvoice.get(pos).setOrder(0);
                    }

                    if (valHasChanged) {
                        notifyItemChanged(pos, ORDER);//notify the adapter that value changed and refresh the view mentioned by the string
                    }
                    if (freeHasChanged) notifyItemChanged(pos, FREE);
                    notifyItemChanged(pos, LINEVAL);

                    lastUpdatedRow = pos;

                }


            }
        });

        holder.free.setOnFocusChangeListener(new FocusChangeListener());
        holder.free.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(String s) {
                boolean valChanged = false;
                int pos = holder.ref;
                if (!onBind) {
                    if ((!s.equals("")) && (!(s.equals("0")))) {

                        int val = Integer.parseInt(s);
                        salesInvoice.get(pos).setFree(val);
                        holder.discount.setEnabled(false);

                        if (salesInvoice.get(pos).getOrder() + salesInvoice.get(pos).getFree() > salesInvoice.get(pos).getStock()) {
                            salesInvoice.get(pos).setFree(0);
                            valChanged = true;
                            holder.discount.setEnabled(true);
                        }

                    } else {
                        salesInvoice.get(pos).setFree(0);

                        holder.discount.setEnabled(true);
                    }

                    notifyItemChanged(pos, LINEVAL);
                    if (valChanged) notifyItemChanged(pos, FREE);
                    holder.setCursor(FREE);

                    lastUpdatedRow = pos;

                }

            }
        });

        holder.discount.setOnFocusChangeListener(new FocusChangeListener());
        holder.discount.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(String s) {
                int pos = holder.ref;
                if (!(s.equals(salesInvoice.get(pos).getDiscountRate() + ""))) {
                    if ((!s.equals("")) && (!(s.equals("0"))) && (!(s.equals("0.0"))) && (!(s.equals("0.")))) {
                        Double rate = Double.parseDouble(s.toString().trim());
                        Log.i(" RAte ", rate + "");
                        salesInvoice.get(pos).setDiscountRate(rate);

                        holder.free.setEnabled(false);


                    } else {
                        salesInvoice.get(pos).setDiscountRate(0.0);
                        holder.free.setEnabled(true);

                    }

                    if (!onBind) {
                        notifyItemChanged(pos, LINEVAL);

                        lastUpdatedRow = pos;

                    }
                }
            }
        });


        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            holder.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        } else {
            holder.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        }

        onBind = false;
        notifyUpdate(); //calling to update the UI

        Log.d("ASY", "before db call");
        DBAdapterAsync dbAdapter = new DBAdapterAsync(getContextForAdapter);
        dbAdapter.execute(salesInvoice.get(holder.ref));
        Log.d("ASY", "after db call");

    }

//async task class for DB Update
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private class DBAdapterAsync extends AsyncTask<SalesInvoiceModel, Void, String> {

        private SQLiteDatabase db;
        private DBHelper dbHelper;

        DBAdapterAsync(Context context) {
            this.dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
            Log.d("ASY", "inside constructor");

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            try {
                db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            try {
                dbHelper.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(SalesInvoiceModel... models) {

            SalesInvoiceModel model = models[0];

            Log.d(TAG, "inside updateInvoiceData_");
            Log.d(TAG, "shelf_" + model.getShelf());
            Log.d(TAG, "order_" + model.getOrder());
            Log.d(TAG, "free_" + model.getFree());

            String sql = "UPDATE temp_invoice SET" +
                    " Shelf=" + model.getShelf() + " , Request=" + model.getRequest()
                    + " , OrderQty=" + model.getOrder() + " , Free=" + model.getFree()
                    + " , Disc=" + model.getDiscountRate() + " , LineVal=" + model.getLineValue()
                    + ", RetailPriceLineVal=" + model.getRetailLineVal()
                    + " WHERE _id=" + model.getId();
            db.execSQL(sql);
            Log.d(TAG, "DB method finished,");
            Log.d("ASY", "after do in background");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add your recycler view adapter code? can't you transfer your code from bindviewholder to ViewHolder? because bindviewholder will call every time u scrool..instead of that ViewHolder will call less times...better if you add adapter code here

Comment: `"So, basically, when each row recycles, [...]"` what do you mean by that? you mean when `RecyclerView.Adapter#onViewRecycled()` is called or what?

Comment: post your adapter and ui update code

Comment: @pskink sorry, I meant when each row gets bound.

Comment: you need to separate the data editing/updating functionality from the data reading implementation. so that you create only one instance of editText objects and Watchers. ie. inside onBindViewHolder show the data to user and create a clickListener for the item. then when the user clicks an item. show a dialog box and do the diting/updating accordingly.